Cursor not-allowed in pseudo element not work in its parent
I have been to look up and see some question in there and its actually relevant to my question: link. However, I tried it to pseudo element like :before or :after then not work?


.pointer-events-none {
    position:relative;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.pointer-events-none:after {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 100%!important;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
<button class="pointer-events-none">Some Text</button>




If you don't want people clicking the button why not just disable it?

@Paulie_D "buttons aren't supposed to have pseudo-elements" - Citation?

Point! I was thinking of input.

What are You trying to do?

I cant put the disabled to button, really I swear. I have no clue with that WHY so this could be the only choice I might dealt with this on today, so please, I really not want this too.

Add following attribute to the pseudo element:
pointer-events: auto;

pointe-events is inherited. Means all children inherit from their parents' pointe-events value. Since you set the button pointer-events: none, you need to set the pseudo element's pointer-events back to auto.


.pointer-events-none {
    position:relative;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.pointer-events-none:after {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 100%!important;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
<button class="pointer-events-none" onclick="console.log('clicked')">Some Text</button>



However, this still triggers the button click events. If you don't want users to click the button, consider using disabled instead.


button[disabled] {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
<button disabled onclick="console.log('clicked')">Some Text</button>



If you don't want to change the appearance of the button and also want to show the not-allowed cursor without triggering the button's click events upon clicking, here's a workaround might be useful.


.button-disabled {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.button-disabled button {
    pointer-events: none;
}
<div class="button-disabled">
  <button onclick="console.log('clicked')">Some Text</button>
</div>



